# Prove Tonelli and Fubinis theorems imply results regarding summation-order of $\sum \sum a_{m,n}$ where $a_{m,n} > 0$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Prove Tonelli and Fubinis theorems imply results regarding summation-order of $\sum \sum a_{m,n}$ where $a_{m,n} > 0$.

I've already proved that $\tau_2 = \tau_1 \otimes \tau_1$ where $\tau_i$ denote the counting measure on $(\mathbb N^i, \mathcal P(\mathbb N^i)$ by considering $\tau_1 \otimes \tau_1(A \times B) = \tau_1(A) \tau_1(B) = \tau_2(A \times B)$, since $|A||B| = |A \times B|$ and using uniqueness.

Now I want to translate Tonellis and Fubinis theorems to results about interchange of sum-order for double-sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n}$.

My idea is:

Let $f(m,n) = a_{m,n}$ for $(m,n) \in \mathbb N^2$. Then

$$\int_{\mathbb N^2} f \ d \tau_2 = \int_{\mathbb N^2} f \ d (\tau_1 \otimes \tau_1) =\int_{\mathbb N} (\int_{\mathbb N} f(m,n) \ \tau_1(dm)) \ \tau_1(dn) = \int_{\mathbb N} (\int_{\mathbb N} f(m,n) \ \tau_1(dn)) \ \tau_1(dm)$$ in the case of Tonelli.

My question is now:

How can I write $\int_{\mathbb N} f(m,n) \ \tau_1(dm) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} a_{m,n}$ (in the case of the inner integral) and how can this be done also for the outer integral ?

How can the above be done for Fubinis theorem ? In Fubinis theorem we consider functions in $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$, but here we assume $a_{m,n} >0$.

Comment: You're absolutely right! For the first question, it either follows directly from your definition of the integral, or by applying the monotone convergence theorem. For this and also for the second question, note that the $\sigma$-algebra on ${\mathbb N}^i$ you are working with is the whole power set, so any function is measurable.

Comment: So you apply monotone convergence theorem to $$f(m,n)1_{[1,k]}(m)$$ where $n$ is fixed ?

Comment: What can I say in case of Fubinis theorem ?

Comment: For the first point: yes. For the second: I'm sorry, I don't know two different theorems here. What I was referring to is the theorem stating that for measurable, non-negative functions on the product of two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, the two iterated integrals exist and agree with the integral over the product space.

Comment: Fubini is just the generalization to a general function in $\mathcal L^1$.